# Creating Classes from Exising Database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, webforms, sql-server-2012

I have ben following through a [tutorial](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/create_the_data_access_layer) that shows how to get started creating a Web Forms Application in ASP.NET...and have got to the part where you create Data Classes. These assume you are starting from scratch and generating the database from code - however - I already have a database created and populated from elsewhere.

Entering line by line to create the Class for each table seems very laborious. (I'm using VB.Net and VS 2013 by the way)

Q1. Can anyone help by suggesting a more automated way of doing this? Surely there is a tool to grab the schema?

Q2. Although the tutorial mentions Entity Framework and Code Behind briefly - having done some reading and research - I am very confused by all of the different terms for data access. Am I using ADO.NET ?? Is the methodology called Code Behind as opposed to something else? Are there better ways to connect to a database and Read/Update/Delete records.

Q3. If I want to use a Data Grid to show the data do I use the generated classes to do this - or just 'bind' the grid directly to the database?

I have been a developer for 40 years but the newer .Net models are causing me some confusion so any advice gratefully received. (and any simple books or tutorials that can be suggested would be helpful).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: What you want is to generate "EF Designer from database" by using a Entity Data Model.

In your project add a new item and look under "Data".

What this technique does is auto generating entity classes from your predefined database.

Q2: I suggest you read [Getting started with Entity Framework](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1). "Database First" is just a description of how you want to use the Entity framework - by saying you already have a database structure.

Comment: Daniel - I worked through the tutorial you suggested which made a lot of sense. I have a Database that doesn't have a Diagram or relationships built in - so when I created the Entity Model the 'Diagram' just shows separate discreet tables...is it necessary to relate the tables for future use - and if so How do you do this? I've been expecting a process that allows a drag of a field to another and then whether 1-to-1 or 1-to many etc...but can't see how it works...

Comment: PhilAJ: Relationships are definitely preferable for many reasons, one of these reasons is data integrity, you don't want to handle this in code only. Here is how to set relationships: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189049.aspx. Do you have MSSQL? Then look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m0-vZZl0QFA

Comment: Thanks Daniel much appreciated. I guess the relationships need to be there before creating the Entities in VS then, or can they be done afterwards once it has been created?

Answer (score 1):

Q3: In this case if you use Entity Framework and the "database first" mechanism to generate entities you can databind the gridview from the result of a entity LINQ query, please see this example: [Tutorial: Databinding](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-net-en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-databinding-linq-entities.html)

Comment: Thanks so much Daniel, starting to make sense.